# ReactJS rendering sub views with url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render sub views (components) into the  based on the navigation menu on the links on  component, changing the url accordingly.  My router is:

```
const router = new Router(on => {

  on('*', async (state, next) => {
    const component = await next();
    return component && <App context={state.context}>{component}</App>;
  });

  on('/profile', async () => <ProfilePage />);

  on('/contact', async () => <ContactPage />);

  on('/login', async () => <LoginPage />);

  on('/register', async () => <RegisterPage />);

  on('*', async (state) => {
    const content = await http.get(`/api/content?path=${state.path}`);
    return content && <ContentPage {...content} />;
  });

  on('error', (state, error) => state.statusCode === 404 ?
    <App context={state.context} error={error}><NotFoundPage /></App> :
    <App context={state.context} error={error}><ErrorPage /></App>);

});

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

  render() {

    var user = "Username";

    return (
      <div>
        <ProfileHead>
          <Cover user={user} />
          <Menu />
          <SubMenu />
        </ProfileHead>
        <ProfileBody>
          <ProfileHome />
        </ProfileBody>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class Menu extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="menu">
        <div className="menu-inner">
          <Nav followers="522234" following="133234" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#" className="menu-link active">Profile</a>
        <a href="#" className="menu-link">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#" className="menu-link">Activity</a>
        <a href="#" className="menu-link">Following <span className="followCount">{this.props.following}</span></a>
        <a href="#" className="menu-link">Followers <span className="followCount">{this.props.followers}</span></a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am not sure how this can be achieved. Any help would would be much appreciated. I am new to React and learning slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [react-router](http://rackt.github.io/react-router)

You can create nested routes which each load other sub component

```
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

// declare our routes and their hierarchy
var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route path="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: I am using this starter kit: http://www.reactstarterkit.com/ and having trouble changing from "react-routing" to "react-router" as I am not familiar with Webpack and other technologies used. Any idea how it can be replaced? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at this: https://github.com/webpack/react-starter. This tutorial should take you through the basics: http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-single-page-react-web-app-with-react-router-and-webpack/